# Filter rows containing date ranges to show only those where a certain date is in the range

Tags: excel

I have this table:

```
Valid From,Valid To,Label
1 Jan 2021,7 Jul 2021,A
1 Feb 2021,7 Jul 2021,B
1 Mar 2021,7 Jul 2021,C
```

I have a "parameter" cell which contains a single date, i.e. `3 Feb 2021`. This is what I consider the "test date". If the test date is in the "valid" range, the row is valid.

Expected output:

```
Valid From,Valid To,Label
1 Jan 2021,7 Jul 2021,A
1 Feb 2021,7 Jul 2021,B
```

Row C is missing, since it's not valid, yet.

I found a lot of examples how to filter tables by a date range (when you have a single date column, the autofilter does all I need) but my case is the opposite: Each row has a date range in which it's valid and I wand to create a read-only view which ansers the question "If today was SOME_DATE, which rows would be valid?"

Ideally, I want the raw data in one sheet and the view plus the "today" cell in another sheet.

What I've managed so far is a view that uses a couple of helper columns:

```
   E          F           G
Visible?,Has Content?,Is In Range?
```

with formulas for Visible?:

```
=AND(F2,G2)
```

(TRUE if the other two are true)

Has Content?:

```
=COUNTA(SourceTable!A2:C2)>0
```

(TRUE if the source table has any data in any cell for the current row)

and lastly for "Is In Range?":

```
=AND($C$2>=SourceTable!A2, $C$2<SourceTable!B2)
```

For each data cell, the formula is:

```
=IF($E2,SourceTable!A2,"")
```

(empty unless the cell in the column "Visible?" is TRUE).

This works but has a few drawbacks:

When more rows are appended to the source table, the view isn't updated. I can work around that by adding 1000 more rows to the view but it feels like a waste of space.

It gets worse when rows are inserted in the middle because Excel then updates the references in my view. The new rows won't show up and I'll suddenly have gaps (i.e when I insert row 10 in the source table, the view will use A9 and then A11, A10 will be missing). Workaround: Use absolute references everywhere.

Lastly, I have those ugly helper columns. Workaround: Hide those columns.

I can get something working but I was wondering if there is a better way?

I'm on Excel 365, Version 2108.

Comment: From your given sample data and output it seems any date in a row is less than single date will be filtered. For first row there is date of January and july. As January is less than February so you want that row to show on desired result. Am I right?

Comment: @Harun24HR I tried to clarify this by editing the question. The "test date" is the input for filtering. If the date range in a row contains this test date, then the row is "valid" and therefore visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is at least a first approximation to an answer:

```
=FILTER(SourceTable!A:C,(ROW(SourceTable!A:C)=1)+(C2>=SourceTable!A:A)*(C2<=SourceTable!B:B)
```

[image]

If you can have either the start date or the finish date (or even both) as blank, indicating an open-ended date range, it will need modifying. The downside of this is that you need to manually format columns E and F as dates.

The formula is very similar to the examples [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759). The filter function lets you set up a filtering array with the same number of rows as your data array, where rows in the filtering array that evaluate to **true** will cause the matching row of the data to be included in the output. In an Excel sheet, anything that is not zero is considered to be true. In array formulas, you can't use AND and OR because they evaluate across the whole array and not row-by row, so you have to use * and + instead.

Actually, hard-coding row 1 is a little crude, this isn't vulnerable to insertion of lines above the data in SourceTable:

```
=FILTER(SourceTable!A:C,(ROW(SourceTable!A:C)=ROW(SourceTable!A1))+(C2>=SourceTable!A:A)*(C2<=SourceTable!B:B))
```

So I have chosen to use

```
ROW(SourceTable!A:C)=ROW(SourceTable!A1)
```

to include the first (header) row of the data, where row(A:C)=row(A1)=1: this only evaluates to TRUE for the first row which I am assuming initially is in the first row of the SourceTable sheet. The reason for using ROW(SourceTable!A1) rather than hard-coding 1 is that if the user inserted a row above the rows containing the data, A1 would automatically update to A2 and the formula would still work.

Then I add to this (OR) the same expression that you used,

```
(C2>=SourceTable!A:A)*(C2<=SourceTable!B:B)
```

but with the AND replaced  by *.

I have used full-column references to avoid issued with deletions and insertions, but this may slow down your sheet a little. If there are no gaps in your label column, it would be possible to use an index/counta combination to restrict the size of the arrays to the number of rows actually used.

```
=LET(rows,COUNTA(SourceTable!C:C),
data,SourceTable!A2:INDEX(SourceTable!C:C,rows),
date1,SourceTable!A2:INDEX(SourceTable!A:A,rows),
date2,SourceTable!B2:INDEX(SourceTable!B:B,rows),
FILTER(data,(ROW(data)=ROW(SourceTable!A1))+(C2>=date1)*(C2<=date2)))
```

*Note*

This formula is indeed much faster than the original, 0.003 vs 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation how the filter works to your answer? Especially the part `(ROW(SourceTable!A:C)=1)+`. I guess `*`with booleans is a kind of AND operator?

Comment: Yes, no problem.